# How to get around curry evaluating its arguments?

Tags: racket, currying

Say I have some function, let's call it `get-io-data`, which gets data from a shell command for example. Now I want a function that checks for something: `check-io-data`. It seems that what should be equivalent ways of defining it end up being different. Using a 'traditional' definition I get a function that gives a result depending on the result of `(get-io-data)` at the time of evaluation. If I use `curry` however, I will get a function that depends on the result of `(get-io-data)` at the time of definition. To make it a bit less confusing here's an example:

Using traditional definition:

```
(define (check-io-data x) (equal? (get-io-data) x))
...
(check-io-data 0) ;; Now (get-io-data) is being evaluated
```

Using curry:

```
(define check-io-data (curry equal? (get-io-data))) ;; Now (get-io-data) is being evaluated
...
(check-io-data 0)
```

I think I know why these are different, because in the first case the entire function body is probably evaluated in a special way because it's a function body, and in the second way I'm defining something to be the result of a function; and this function is evaluated at define-time to get the actual definition and to evaluate the function it has to evaluate the arguments.

Is there a way to do this point-free or is that just not gonna work? And theoretically speaking, shouldn't these two definitions be exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple answer

The syntax would be,

```
(define (check-io-data data) 
  ((curry equal?) (get-io-data) data))
```

#### Discussion

Because `check-io-data` is a function of one argument, it must be defined as such. Because `equal?` is a function with arity = 2, it must be passed two arguments when curried.

In schematic form, this:

```
> (define f (lambda (x) (equal? 'curried-argument x)))
> (f 'curried-argument)
#t
> (f 1)
#f
```

Is equivalent to:

```
> (define (f x) ((curry equal?) 'curried-argument x))
> (f 'curried-argument)
#t
> (f 1)
#f
```

#### Illustrative example

```
#lang racket

;;; Use a generator to simulate
;;; a non-idempotent procedure
(require racket/generator)
(define get-io-data
  (infinite-generator
   (yield 1)
   (yield 2)
   (yield 3)))

(define (check-io-data x)
  ((curry equal?) (get-io-data) x))

(check-io-data 1)  ; #t
(check-io-data 1)  ; #f
(check-io-data 1)  ; #f
(check-io-data 1)  ; #t
```

#### Conclusion

A curried function has to `define` itself as a function [i.e. `(define (name arg...)(body))` ] to establish the arity of the `lambda` created by `curry`.